# EXEC with an EXEC

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have an EXEC within an EXEC in SQL?

e.g. EXEC('EXEC ...')

Comment: Surely as quick to try as to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, yes.  try:

```
EXEC ('EXEC sp_helpdb')
```

or

```
EXEC ('EXEC (''EXEC sp_helpdb'')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With an exec statement you can call any statement you could write into a Management Studio query batch including another exec statement.